# regex in php using preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to make a php file so it can accept  word for a regex (a+b)(ab+ba)*
i am using preg_match and so far ive come up with this

```
    $subject = "a+b";
    $pattern = '(([a]{1}\+[b]{1})?([ab]{1}\+[ba]{1}))';
    preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
```

I am not sure if i completely understand how it works but its been few hours now I am trying to figure out.. how do i make it so it fullfills my condition

I want to match (a+b)(ab+ba)* where the first bracket (a+b) is required and  the * on the second bracket (ab+ba) means that there could be zero or multiple instances of it.
so it should work like this

```
   $subject= "(a+b)"
   Match


   $subject= "(a+b)(ab+ba)"
   Match


   $subject= "(a+b)(ab+ba)(ab+ba)"
   Match

   $subject= "(ab+ba)"
   No Match

   $subject= ""
   No Match
```

Comment: What you are trying to match isn't very clear, could you add other examples?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I have edited the original post, please have a look.

Comment: In your code snippet `$subject` doesn't include parentheses but in next samples it does. Which one is correct?

Comment: My bad, the second one is correct it must contain parenthesis, i was just testing if it works for a+b when it should not and should only works for (a+b). @revo

Comment: You need to escape special characters `(?:\(a\+b\))(?:\(ab\+ba\))*`

Comment: @revo yeah it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `(([a]{1}\+[b]{1})?([ab]{1}\+[ba]{1}))`

`[a]{1}` (1 character in a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)) can be written as `a`

`[b]{1}` can be written as `b`

`[ab]` (2 characters in a character class) means a or b

I think you have to escape the opening parenthesis `\(`, or else you would start a capturing group.

If I am not mistaken, this might match what you are looking for:

[`^\(a\+b\)(?:\(ab\+ba\))*$`](https://regex101.com/r/ihVMPO/3)

The second part is in a non capturing group `(?:\(ab\+ba\))*` and repeated zero or more times.

[Php test ouput](https://3v4l.org/3Lqpq)

Comment: its just perfect tbut thers one problem it also works for words like (a+b)(, (a+b)a, etc.
Like it works for (a+b) and anything after that

Comment: @YousufKhan Then you could use anchors for the beginning `^` and end `$` of the string. I have updated my answer.

Comment: yeah it worked, I was putting $ at the beginning and it wasnt working.